# Compilation Fails to recognize java.awt.image.DataBufferInt class

Tags: java

Can someone please identify for me the error in this line of code?  I amm using eclipse Mars 2.1.  This line is always flagged as the sole error in a short program of mine.  I have tried using both styles of import (i.e. top of the class and inline as below ).  Both result in eclipse flagging the line as an error with a red x (nothing useful by clicking on it ) and when I try to run I get "Exception in thread main java.lang.error: unresolved compilation problem ).  It seems to me its not recognizing the identifier for that class and this prevents it from compiling properly.

```
private int[] pixels = ((java.awt.image.DataBufferInt))image.getRaster().getDataBuffer().getData());
```

Comment: Don't try to run code that doesn't even compile. Open the problems view, and **read** the compilation error message. Your parentheses aren't balanced.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  The problems view says java.awt.image.DataBufferInt cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: There is an extra parenthesis in there - overlooked it when I typed the code into this site.  So just want to note thats not it.

Comment: Post the **actual** code that doesn't compile.

Comment: oh my god... aargh... do I feel like an a**.  Simple matter of parenthesis.  I haven't done any coding in over a year.  That's rust I just got all over you :)